# How to collect articles for my new Article Directory

Tags: website-design, copyright

I've an idea and just want suggestions and comments about it.

I'm launching an free article directory, which as usual will allow to have author's dofollow backlinks.

How do I get good articles?

Can I contact the authors of articles published in other article directories and ask their permission to allow me to republish the same article?

Comment: FYI, this is exactly what Google doesn't want. Those articles are low quality and republishing them makes them duplicate content. Basically everything their Panda algorithm is out to get. If you're hoping to get traffic from Google I'd say you have no chance of succeeding.

Comment: No, even EzineArticles.com isn't averse to this(they replied me, they have no problem as long as copyright isn't compromised). Moreover just like forums my site will need some "warming up" before people really start submitting articles. Moreover a professional article submitter always submits it to many article directories.

Comment: EzineArticles.com is definitely affected by this. What they told you was what you wanted to hear (and what they want everyone to believe). If you want to get site "warmed up" either write unique quality content for it or get others to do it for you. But putting those low quality duplicate content in your site definitely won't help it and probably will hurt it since most of your website, if not all of it, will be low quality.

Comment: John I don't know why you want to discourage me. I told I could contact the authors of good articles, after all they want is backlinks for their sites. Where is the case of low content then? Why do you want to close your eyes for the fact that every professional article submitter submits the (good/bad) article to as many article directories as she can

Comment: I'm not trying to discourage you. I'm just telling you how it is. Those articles are low quality because they offer no new or useful information. That's bad. Plus by being published on more then on website they are, by definition, duplicate content. That's bad, too. If you think this is going to make your website better it isn't. It you think this will help you in the search engines it isn't.

Comment: The best thing that can happen is nothing. The worst is your site goes into Google hell. It's not worth the risk as there is no reward.

Comment: Does your comment apply to EzineArticles.com too?

Comment: @JohnConde let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/898/discussion-between-john-and-john-conde)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a *catch-22* in there. To get more articles you have to get some good ranking. To get some good ranking, you have to have some good articles.

You need to bootstrap the process then and that means creating new articles for your directory. Do not use - even with permission - articles from elsewhere or your site will not get much ranking and therefore wont attract many articles.

These are just guesses, I have never done this, but you could try:

- Hiring some writers from a freelance site. Given them topics and an idea of the size of articles you want.
- Contact people with creative content that **are not** articles. Maybe someone has a book would like to write an article on the same topic. Or authors of video tutorials, etc.

What I would also suggest is try to get a theme of your directory. This means that the links and contents you get will be more focused and you will have a better chance of ranking for anything.

Comment: I'm not looking for site ranking at all. In my country there little competition so ranking isn't a issue. Most important is that when anybody visits my site, one should get a feeling of a live/running site rather than having no articles. Once my site catches up, I'll be happy to remove all those duplicates. My ultimate target is Adsense only.

Comment: I am not sure how much Google will prioritize a poor local site over a good site anywhere. You may not get any traffic to monetize AdSense without the ranking. Plus, there is nothing wrong doing the right thing in the first place. Remember the authors need something to gain too, otherwise they won't help you. If they let you use the article without cost it would be for getting links. Without ranking those have very little value.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would have done a research before jumping into the "Article Marketing" niche. The way I see it, these sites aren't reaping huge benefits as they used to do it in the past, and rightly deserves to stay down in the SERPs -- apart from the handful of article directories, most of them are junk.

If are still willing to run an article site, then go ahead and call someone from the freelance community. You can ask them to mail the other writers and post the article with permission. Otherwise you can always advertise your site with a unique title -- Article Marketing for your __ Business in *_* (Place), for instance.